# Conditional inclusion: numeric value for the character constants: within #if/#elif vs. without #if/#elif: why matching is implementation-defined?

Tags: c, constants, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, implementation-defined-behavior

Case A: C11, 6.6 Constant expressions, Semantics, 5:

> If a floating expression is evaluated in the translation environment, the arithmetic range and precision shall be at least as great as if the expression were being evaluated in the execution
> environment.<sup>116)</sup>

which requires the following program to return 0:

```
#include <float.h>

#define EXPR DBL_MIN * DBL_MAX

double d1 = EXPR;
double d2;

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(void)
{
    d2 = EXPR;
    return d1 == d2 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Case B: C11, 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion, Semantics, 4:

> Whether the numeric value for these character constants matches the value obtained when an identical character constant occurs in an expression (other than within a #if or #elif directive) is implementation-defined.<sup>168)</sup>

which *does not* require the following program to return 0:

```
#define EXPR 'z' - 'a' == 25

int main(void)
{
    _Bool b1 = 0;
    _Bool b2;
#if EXPR
    b1 = 1;
#endif
    b2 = EXPR;
    return b1 == b2 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Question: what is the rationale for making "Case B" implementation-defined behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C11 Standard (I shall be quoting from [this draft document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) defines two character sets:

> ##### 5.2.1 Character sets
>
> 1     Two sets of characters and their associated collating sequences shall be defined:
> the set in which source files are written (the *source character set*),
> and the set interpreted in the execution environment (the *execution character set*). Each set is further divided into a *basic character set*, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or
> more locale-specific members (which are not members of the basic
> character set) called extended characters. The combined set is also
> called the *extended character set*. The values of the members of the
> execution character set are implementation-defined.

Furthermore, there is no requirement that equivalent characters in those sets are represented by the same *values*, and neither is there any requirement that Latin letters are stored in sequence. So, in the example given, the value of `'z' - 'a'` need not be the same in those two sets.

Now, the order of translation phases specifies that macro invocations and evaluations (and other pre-processing directives) are performed using the *source character set* but expressions that occur in executable code are evaluated **after conversion to** the *execution character set*:

> ##### 5.1.1.2 Translation phases
>
> …
> 4.     Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and **`_Pragma`** unary operator expressions are
> executed. If a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
> universal character name is produced by token concatenation
> (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A **`#include`** preprocessing
> directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from
> phase 1 through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are
> then deleted.
> 5.     Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and string literals is converted to the corresponding member
> of the execution character set; if there is no corresponding member,
> it is converted to an implementation-defined member other than the
> null (wide) character.
> …

Thus, because the relationship between those character sets is implementation-defined, and because the two occurrences of the character-based constant expressions are *defined* to use different sets, the fact that they may have different evaluations **must also be implementation-defined**.